# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.ensemble.voting_classifier'

Tags: python-3.x, sklearn-pandas, ensemble-learning

I am trying to load a pickle file using below code.

`# Load model from file classiferM1 = joblib.load("Model 1_ensemble.pkl")`

Now I am facing error
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.ensemble.voting_classifier'`

I understand that sklearn has this module as `sklearn.ensemble.VotingClassifier`.

Please let me know how I can overcome this error, can I edit the pickle file code?

Thanks and Regards,
Surendra.

Comment: what version of sklearn are you using?

Comment: Version of sklearn is  `sklearn              0.0`

Answer (score 0):

You Have Typo mistake the original module name is `VotingClassifier` but you have written  `sklearn.ensemble.voting_classifier` in your code.  Change `from sklearn.ensemble import voting_classifier` into `from sklearn.ensemble import VotingClassifier` in your code..

Comment: for that I need to edit my pickle file, could you please suggest how to edit pickle file.

Comment: https://stackabuse.com/scikit-learn-save-and-restore-models/ Refer the below link...@Surendra_Suri

Comment: I tried with pickle library, now I am facing following error. `UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\x1f'.`

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved by installing Anaconda 2.7.